# Unable to debug Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In sharepoint Project(Solution File) I am having a silverlight project(Project A) and Class library(Project B).In the class library I have referred the silverlight project(Project A) in Project B. Here is the code in Project B

```
<object id="Sample_ID" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
        <param name="source" value="/_layouts/clientbin/Sample.xap">
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError">
                <param name="background" value="transparent">
                    <param name="initParams" value="Name=Sample">
                        <param name="isWindowless" value="true">
                        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0">
                        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true">
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&amp;v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none">             
</object>
```

I am unable to debug the silverlight project. I have gone through the following links but it didn't help me
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838267(v=vs.95).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/68127/Unable-to-DEBUG-Silverlight-project
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/bb6dd346-a3c6-4ab2-95fd-3e6c76280e17/

Could anyone provide a solution for this issue ?

Comment: so you have ensured the debugger is attached, as per the msdn article?  While I develop silverlight, VS2010 won't always attach to the silverlight process by default.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you haven't enabled javascript debugging, which in turn disables Silverlight debugging.

In the solution explorer, locate your web project (in your case, this would be Project B?), right click and select *Properties*.
Go to the Web tab, in the details panel scroll down so you can see the *Debuggers* section at the bottom. Ensure that the `ASP.NET` and `Silverlight` options are checked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have verified the debugger options in the project properties tab it is checked only. But still I am unable to debug it. Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue more than a few times and I usually do the following:

1. Manually delete all of the binaries generated at build (similar to Clean)
2. Remove the Silverlight application from the hosting web project (under Silverlight Applications tab in project properties) and add it into the project again
3. Restart Visual Studio

Also, you may want to double check that your debugging project has Silverlight (under Web tab in project properties) though I believe VS2010 typically prompts if you want to do this anyways